# throws of coin, when is greater probablity?

Tags: probability

Hansel and Gretel throwing coins: Hansel throws $n$ times and Gretel $ n + 1 $ times. What is the probability that Gretel falls more eagles than Hansel?

Comment: Where did the eagles come from?

Comment: @Null: Evidently one side of the coin shows an eagle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After each has tossed $n$ times, there are three possibilities: (i) H has more eagles; (ii) G has more eagles; (iii) they are tied.

Note that (i) and (ii) are equally likely.

Now consider G's last toss. In case (i) she will for sure not end up with **more** eagles than H. In case (ii) she will end up with more.

And, if the coin is fair, in case (iii) she is equally likely to end up with more as with the same.

Thus the probability G will end up with **more** eagles is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: more formally, please :)

Answer (score 1):

André has given the easiest and nicest solution. A more computational approach is also possible, however, and it also yields the probabilities of a drawn game and of a win for Hansel.

Consider the state of affairs after both have tossed their coins $n$ times. There are $2^n$ possible sequences of results for each of them, so there are $2^{2n}$ possible outcomes altogether (where an outcome is a specific string of tosses for each of them). The number of outcomes in which Hansel and Gretel end up with the same number of eagles at this point is

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k^2=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k\binom{n}{n-k}=\binom{2n}n\;.$$

The game up to this point is symmetric, so each of them wins half of the remaining outcomes, or

$$\frac12\left(2^{2n}-\binom{2n}n\right)=2^{2n-1}-\frac12\binom{2n}n\;.$$

Each of these winning outcomes for Gretel corresponds to two winning outcomes for her in the full game, one in which her final toss is an eagle and one in which it isn’t, so they account for $$2^{2n}-\binom{2n}n$$ winning outcomes for her in the full game.

In the full game Gretel also wins every outcome in which she tosses an eagle after the game was tied after $n$ tosses apiece; that’s another $\binom{2n}n$ winning outcomes for her, for a total of $2^{2n}$ winning outcomes out of $2^n\cdot2^{n+1}=2^{2n+1}$ possible outcomes of the full game. In other words, she wins the full game with probability $\frac12$.

We can also calculate the probability that the full game ends in a tie. That happens when the shorter game is tied and Gretel does not toss an eagle on her final throw, and when Hansel is up by one at the end of the shorter game and Gretel does toss an eagle on her final throw. We already know that the first case accounts for $\binom{2n}n$ outcomes of the full game. The second accounts for another

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k\binom{n}{k+1}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{n-k}\binom{n}{k+1}=\binom{2n}{n+1}$$

outcomes in the full game, for a total of

$$\binom{2n}n+\binom{2n}{n+1}=\binom{2n+1}{n+1}=\binom{2n+1}n$$

outcomes and a probability of $$2^{-2n-1}\binom{2n+1}n\;.$$

Finally, subtracting this from $\frac12$ gives the probability that Hansel wins.

For example, if $n=2$, Gretel wins with probability $\frac12$, the game ends in a tie with probability $$\frac1{32}\binom52=\frac{10}{32}=\frac5{16}\;,$$ and Hansel wins with probability $$\frac12-\frac5{16}=\frac3{16}$. The $6$ outcomes in which Hansel wins are the $2$ in which he throws one eagle and Gretel throws none, and the $4$ in which he throws two eagles and Gretel throws at most one.